# Publishing in Mathematics and Computer Science related journals

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, computer-science, open-access

I have seen Elsevier journals offer Gold open access and Green open access options, when I was checking for journals related to Mathematics and Computer Science.

I have understood that Gold open access can be gained by making a publication fee. However they have mentioned that waivers are offered for countries eligible for Research4Life program.

Can someone help me to understand whether you have to be a part of some program to have this waiver? i.e. if you are in a country mentioned in the Research4Life program page in Elsevier, do you get free publication open access in Gold open access journals?

https://www.elsevier.com/about/corporate-responsibility/research4life

And do Elsevier and Springer offer reductions or discounts in Article Processing Charges for low income countries?

Can someone please advise if you are aware of this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you email the journal editors to ask? What did they say?

Answer (score 1):

The rules for Elsevier are stated [on this page](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/open-access/choice#waivers).  Essentially, as long as all authors of your paper work at institutions in [countries in "Group A"](https://www.research4life.org/access/eligibility/) then you get a full waiver.  If any author's affiliation is outside this set of countries, you don't (there is also a set of countries that get a 50% waiver).

It's unclear whether you can get a waiver if you don't have any institutional affiliation.  I suspect it may be difficult, since Elsevier is huge and the system is supposed to work automatically by detecting your country of affiliation.  If they don't even respond to an email to support, I wouldn't be optimistic.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidKetcheson